# Question about statements of Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

I have some questions about the two versions of Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem given in Folland's book "Real Analysis"

Version 1:

> Given a compact Hausdorff space $X$, let $F$ be an equicontinuous, pointwise bounded subset of $C(X)$, the set of complex-valued continuous functions on $X$. The, $F$ is totally bounded in the uniform metric and the closure of $F$ in $C(X)$ is compact.

(Q1)  The uniform metric is not well-defined for all $f \in C(x)$, so what does it mean to say that $F$ is totally bounded in the uniform metric? Also, how do we take the closure with respect to this metric?

Version 2:

> If $X$ is a $\sigma$-compact locally compact Hausdorff space, $\dots$

Isn't $\sigma$-compact space always locally compact? Why is it assumed that the space is both $\sigma-$compact and locally compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniform metric in $C(X)$ is defined by $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in X}\bigl|f(x)-g(x)\bigr|$. This makes sense for *any* two functions $f,g\in C(X)$, since $X$ is compact, which implies that $f-g$ is bounded.

On the other hand $\mathbb Q$ (with the usual topology) is $\sigma$-compact, since it's the union of all of its singletons, but not locally compact.

Comment: why is $\mathbb{Q}$ not locally compact?

Comment: @nan Because no subset of $\mathbb Q$ which contains a set of the form $(a,b)\cap\mathbb Q$ is compact. And this is so because, since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, every such set contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence (just take a sequence which converges, in $\mathbb R$, to an irrational number).

Comment: By the way, could you recommend some book from which I can learn basic topology?

Comment: I suggest Willard's *General Topology*.

Comment: If $X$ is locally compact and $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff, the compact open topology on $C(X)$ is metrisable.